# Visual Composer 4.7.4 - Shortcodes in Backend

Tags: wordpress

After upgrading Visual Composer from 4.1.3 to 4.7.4 (security update for the new XSS vulnerability) I see numerous shortcodes in "Backend-Editor"-Mode (the graphical/visual part). The shortcodes are editable when opening the container, they render fine in front end, so they should be a functional block in the backend; not a texted shortcode.

Among others, these are the most frequent: [text_output], [/text_output], [gap …], [vc_row_inner ..]

Any suggestions of what went wrong? I can reproduce this with around 5 installations, the themes author blames the deprecated theme version - but I don't see why: [vc_row_inner ..] was in 4.1.x and is in 4.7.x a valid shortcode for native VC..